How to customize task pop layout on the activities menu?
Does anyone know if its possible to edit the layout of the task pop up in the image below?
I have tried editing the task layout page, the  search layout page on activities and the compact layout with no luck


Customizing the new task layout on the activities menu edit the Global Actions layout.

Go to Setup.
Enter Global Actions in the Quick Find box.
Select Global Actions.
Next to the New Task, click on Layout.

This will allow you to customize the fields and layout that appear when creating a new task from the activities menu.

